# What does the injector does that global variables can't?

Tags: angularjs

so in the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#injector) I saw this about the injector:

```
// You write functions such as this one.
function doSomething(serviceA, serviceB) {
  // do something here.
}

// Angular provides the injector for your application
var $injector = ...;

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// the old-school way of getting dependencies.
var serviceA = $injector.get('serviceA');
var serviceB = $injector.get('serviceB');

// now call the function
doSomething(serviceA, serviceB);

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// the cool way of getting dependencies.
// the $injector will supply the arguments to the function automatically
$injector.invoke(doSomething); // This is how the framework calls your functions
```

it looks nice. but i don't get it. in the last line where the injector looks for dependencies, isn't it exactly like having global variables serviceA, serviceB? I mean, say I would rewrite it like this:

```
var serviceA, serviceB; 
function doSomething() {
   // access serviceA, serviceB
}
```

what is the benefit of having the injector do that? I mean, if he can magically find the right objects for the arguments, doesn't it mean I can find them just as easily if they are global variables?

I hope my question is clear...

Comment: I think the real use is that 1) the injector is module-bound (so no global vars). And 2) testability, which would be hard with global state.

Comment: I need to write that memo "Javascript Globals Are Bad". Oh wait, it's already been done. ;-) It's not that they're bad, it's just that using them increases the chances of over-writing and collisions. Also, as Yoshi said, injection makes testing so much easier.

Answer (score -1):

BTW, if you're doing something that genuinely needs to be at a lower level than $scope, Angular has you covered:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope)

The docs for $rootScope are a little light, but generally speaking, you inject it and use it the same as regular $scope. It is the shared root scope of the app you're in.

The only reason to use Window scope would be to communicate between multiple Angular apps. And even then...you got it, Angular has you covered:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$window](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24window)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is more of a comment. It looks like it answers some ancillary questions that were in an earlier draft of the question but are not there anymore.